# How can I concatenate matrices of different dimensions using zeros as fillers?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to concatenate matrices with different dimensions by filling the shorter matrices with "zeros". How one would do that in a for loop?

For example, I have a data set called `x` that is a (92x1) vector. I want to truncate this vector several times, by deleting successive 10 rows (92x1, 82x1, 72x1, 62x1... 2x1) and then combine all the resulting vectors into one matrix that has 9 columns.

I used the code:

```
CN_trunc = zeros(92, 9);
for i = 1:9
    CN_trunc(:,:) = x(1:(92 - i*10), 1));
end
```

and I keep getting a `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch` error. How I could successively delete rows from my vector, and then concatenate them all into one matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based [`vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) approach to solve it -

```
%// Sample Input and cutting/deleting length
x = rand(12,1) %// For your actual problem x would be of length 92
cutlen = 5;    %// Edit this to 10 for your stated problem

lens = numel(x):-cutlen:1;
out = bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@ge,lens,[1:max(lens)]'),x(:))
```

Sample run -

```
x =
    0.6679
    0.6035
    0.5261
    0.7297
    0.7073
    0.7814
    0.2880
    0.6925
    0.5567
    0.3965
    0.0616
    0.7802
out =
    0.6679    0.6679    0.6679
    0.6035    0.6035    0.6035
    0.5261    0.5261         0
    0.7297    0.7297         0
    0.7073    0.7073         0
    0.7814    0.7814         0
    0.2880    0.2880         0
    0.6925         0         0
    0.5567         0         0
    0.3965         0         0
    0.0616         0         0
    0.7802         0         0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following simple solution

```
CN_trunc = zeros(92, 10);
for i = 1:10
    CN_trunc(1:(92 - (i-1)*10),i) = x(1:(92 - (i-1)*10));
end
```